# I am replacing a burned upper thermostat to my water heater. How do I replace the wire leading to the thermostat?

Tags: electrical, wiring

The upper thermostat of my whirlpool water heater burned, and I am going to replace it.  I'm pretty sure I figured out why.

My problem is that I don't know how to get into it to replace the wire that brings the power into the thermostat.

I'm pretty sure if the thermostat burned, the wire must have also gotten damaged.

How do I replace the wire leading to the thermostat?

Comment: Giving us the model number of the unit and providing some pictures of what you've got so far would be helpful in determining an answer.

Comment: If the wires are damaged it can be difficult to impossible to get to them.  It depends on the WH unit's construction.  Some can have their covers removed, others not so much.  Before doing that, however, I'd check to see if the wires are good and not shorting to ground with a voltmeter.

Comment: Not at home, but it's a basic water heater.  The junction box is on top, and the wire runs to the upper thermostat through the inside of the water heater.  I don't know if there's a way to take off the whole junction box.  I've read where people couldn't get the wire in so they ran a wire on the outside, which sounds dubious to me.....

Comment: When you get home use the internet to search for the service manual of the make & model of your WH and see if you can learn more from that. If not post some photos of the WH  and the junction box,  plus make and model etc.

Comment: Added a picture of what it looks like.

Comment: @Robert The photo you posted had nothing to do with water  heaters.

Comment: I don't even see what I posted.  Apparently something went wrong.

Comment: Looks like this: https://mobileimages.lowes.com/product/converted/035505/035505862846.jpg?size=pdhi

Comment: Is the insulation around tank foam or fiberglass?

Comment: @Robert I edited it away because it was a photo of some Jazz LP album covers. (*Nice but not relevant*) The stock photo in  the link you just posted tells us nothing other than it is an electric tank WH. **When you get home use the internet to search for the service manual of the make & model of your WH and see if you can learn more from that. If not post some photos of the WH and the junction box, plus make and model etc**

Comment: [This site](http://waterheatertimer.org/How-to-rewire-electric-water-heater.html) shows how you can carefully drill a new pathway through the foam type insulation from the junction box to the thermostats.

Comment: @Kris - Love the stick figure illustrations. Robert, you should probably diagnose that the wire is the problem and needs to be replaced **before    drilling**.

Answer (score 1):

Before you replace the wire test it to see if it is damaged. First shut the breaker off to the water heater. Next separate the power cable from the water heater wire. The water heater's power wire usually runs to the thermostat. Remove it from the terminal screw. With a continuity tester touch a lead to each end of the black wire which should show continuity. Next with one lead on the wire touch the other to the metal tank and outer shell. You should not see continuity (which is good).

If you do need to replace a wire: with the power still off, tape the new wire around one end of the old wire securely and slowly pull the other end of the old wire until the new one reaches where it will go. Use he old wire as a lead to pull new.